# How to update rows based on a shared ID within a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have a table that looks like below:

```
ID|Date    |Val1|Val2|        
1 |1/1/2016|1000|0         
2 |1/1/2016|Null|0  
3 |1/1/2016|Null|0  
1 |2/1/2016|1000|0  
2 |2/1/2016|Null|0  
3 |2/1/2016|1000|0 
1 |3/1/2016|1000|0   
2 |3/1/2016|1000|0   
3 |3/1/2016|1000|0
```

I want `val2` to become `1` if `Val1` is populated in the previous `month`, so the output would look like:

```
ID|Date    |Val1|Val2|        
1 |1/1/2016|1000|0         
2 |1/1/2016|Null|0  
3 |1/1/2016|Null|0      
1 |2/1/2016|1000|1   
2 |2/1/2016|Null|0  
3 |2/1/2016|1000|0     
1 |3/1/2016|1000|1  
2 |3/1/2016|1000|0   
3 |3/1/2016|1000|1
```

I've tried a few code combinations, but the conditional of updating the value by the previous date where `Val1` first appears is tripping me up. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: What is the datatype of the `Date-----` column?  As written, it looks like a `VARCHAR` instead of a `DATE`.

Comment: Do you have other days of the month (not 1st) in your table?  Can you have more than one record for a given ID **and** Date?

Comment: could you explain more why there is only 1 from val2 for Feb. but two 1 for Mar.?

Comment: I do not have other days of the month other than the first.

Date is a date column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a windowed `LAG()` to find the previous value, and update `Val2` if it's `NOT NULL`.

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  Id, [Date-----], Val1, Val2,
            Lag(Val1) Over (Partition By Id Order By [Date-----] Asc) As Prev
    From    LikeBelow
)
Update  Cte
Set     Val2 = 1 
Where   Prev Is Not Null;
```

If you are actually storing your dates as a `VARCHAR` and not a `DATE`, you'll need to convert it:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  Id, [Date-----], Val1, Val2,
            Lag(Val1) Over (Partition By Id 
                            Order By Convert(Date, [Date-----]) Asc) As Prev
    From    LikeBelow
)
Update  Cte
Set     Val2 = 1 
Where   Prev Is Not Null;
```

Comment: This didn't work using the CTE, but selecting the values into a separate table, then running this query achieved the desired result.